# Не могу установить бота Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, бот

не получается установить бота Telegram, перепробовал уже кучу всего..Но, не получается и все..Каждый раз разные ошибки..

через python3

```
root@fhdf:~/vov# python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import menu
  File "/root/vov/menu.py", line 1, in <module>
    from telebot import types
ImportError: cannot import name 'types'
```

Установленные библиотеки

```
root@fhdf:~/vov# pip freeze
asn1crypto==0.24.0
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
configobj==5.0.6
cryptography==2.1.4
decorator==4.1.2
enum34==1.1.6
idna==2.6
ipaddress==1.0.17
keyring==10.6.0
keyrings.alt==3.0
pycrypto==2.6.1
pygobject==3.26.1
pyTelegramBotAPI==3.7.7
pyudev==0.21.0
pyxdg==0.25
requests==2.25.1
SecretStorage==2.3.1
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.26.4
root@fhdf:~/vov#
```

Через python

```
root@fhdf:~/vov# python main.py
  File "main.py", line 42
    bot.send_message(chat_id=func.admin_id_own(), text=f"Новый пользователь @{me                                                  ssage.chat.username}")
                                                                                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
root@fhdf:~/vov#
```

Comment: В `/root/vov` есть файл `telebot.py`? В второй ошибке разорвана переменная в строке, там не должны быть пробелы: `@{me                                                  ssage`

Comment: Нет, там нет такого файла, в коде нет пробелов простоя коряво скопировал.

Comment: Ок, убедитесь что питон, на который поставили библиотеку бота, тот же, что который запускаете. Попробуйте использовать не `pip`, а `pip3`

Comment: Так я написал , что и там и там ошибка.Выше все указано и какие ошибки..

Comment: По вашему, чем `python` отличается от `python3`, и `pip` от `pip3`? :) `python` скорее всего у вас, раз линукс, это `python2`, тогда понятно почему ошибка синтаксиса при использовании f-строк и почему при установленных в python2 библиотеках, не видит их при запуске в python3

Comment: Я не особо разбираюсь в этом) Можно пример команды? Как мне запустить файл с помощью `pip или pip3`

Comment: Я делал все по инструкции, чтобы запустить бота была команда `python main.py`и `python3 main.py` обе выдают ошибки..

Comment: Чтобы установить на python3 используйте: `pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI`, или аналог через сам питон: `python3 -m pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`. А запускайте бота от `python3`

Comment: Установил все, проблема таже..

Comment: Вы поставили в python3/pip3 библиотеку и все-равно при запуске `python3 main.py` у вас ругается на `ImportError: cannot import name 'types'`?

Comment: Спасибо решил проблему..Не можешь подсказать как сделать чтобы сервер не отрубался при закрытии путти? У меня на хостинге стоит , но когда закрываю путти бот вырубается.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не знаю... Мои боты на моей же машине запущены (win10). Напишите мне сюда в комментарии, когда разберетесь с этой проблемой :)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решил. Установил библиотеку `sudo apt-get install python3-pil` и все заработало.